# I received (admission / acceptance / admittance) from

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Are the following sentences different semantically:

> - I received **admission** from UCLA.
> - I received **acceptance** from UCLA.
> - I received **admittance** from UCLA.

I guess the third one is used very rarely and perhaps never and the first tow sentences can be used interchangeably; do you confirm my take?

Answer (score 1):

Both the first and third statement say roughly the same thing (though your choice of words will sound odd to a native speaker). The second, however, makes it sound like UCLA showed you approval or a favorable reception, not permission to study there.

If you change the **from**'s to **to**'s, however, the three sentences would be interchangeable.

> - I received admission to UCLA.
> - I received acceptance to UCLA.
> - I received admittance to UCLA.